# Get JSON data on my android

Tags: android, json

> Hello am trying to get the following JSON data on my android. A case link can be http://digitaresolutions.com/apps/drugindex/getbrand.php?id=bactiflox. Is there anyone who can help me fetch this; Note: The array has a single object.

```
public class Search_view extends AppCompatActivity {
    String brandURL = "http://digitaresolutions.com/apps/drugindex/getbrand.php?id=";
    TextView txtProduct;

    String product;
    String url="";

    TextView outputText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.brand_item);

        txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brand_label);

        // getting attached intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();
        product = i.getStringExtra("product");

        // displaying selected product name
        url = brandURL + product;
        txtProduct.setText("Drug Molecule: " + product + "\n Product Url: " + url);

        new JSONParse().execute();
   }

    // JSON Parsing
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drug_info);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Search_view.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            outputText.setText("Getting Brand Please wait..");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String content = MyHttpUrlConnection.getData(url);
            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(content);
                JSONArray drug = obj.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < drug.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject p = (JSONObject) drug.get(i);

                    String drg = (String) drug.get(i);
                    Log.i("Drug Info", drg);

                    sb.append(i + 1 + " Manufacturer : " + p.getString("manu") + "\n");
                    sb.append("Drug Info : " + p.getString("details") + "\n");
                }

                return sb.toString();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            outputText.setText(result);
        }
    }
        // End JSON JSON Parsing
}
```

**The Following code is my `Http Url` Connector:**

```
    public class MyHttpUrlConnection {

    public static String getData(String uri) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setReadTimeout(10000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.connect();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            String data = null;
            String webPage = "";
            while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                webPage += data + "\n";
            }
            return webPage;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this a get or post request?

Comment: Please take a look at Volley: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: It is a get request. Am using an intent value from a previous activity to complete the url: "http://digitaresolutions.com/apps/drugindex/getbrand.php?id=" as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this way.

Create global variables

```
InputStream inputStream;
int res_code;
```

I create a class which extends AsyncTask

```
 public class GetJsonData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://digitaresolutions.com/apps/drugindex/getbrand.php?id=bactiflox");

            request.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");

            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = client.execute(request);

                Log.d("Response of GET request", response.toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            res_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            //Printing server response
            System.out.println("server response is :" + result + "\n" + inputStream);


            try {

               JsonObject jo new JSONObject(result);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientServerDemo", "Error:", e);


        }

        return true;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        //display the progress dialog


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean valid) {

        //dismiss the progress dialog

        if (inputStream != null){

        }
    }

}
```

I am using one function. Please add the method after adding the class

```
public String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        result += line;
        System.out.println("---->"+line);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

This works for me..

ps: if you can't import the HTTP classes, then add the following in the module's build.gradle

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

after

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

in the

```
android{

}
```

All the best

Comment: inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            res_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            //Printing server response
            System.out.println("server response is :" + result + "\n" + inputStream);

Comment: Given that Java is case sensitive; should it not be something like this?                 InputStream  x= response.getEntity().getContent();
                String result = convertInputStreamToString(x);
                int res_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                //Printing server response
                System.out.println("server response is :" + result + "\n" + res_code);

Comment: define globally InputStream inputStream; and int res_code. I updated the answer including this part

Comment: Thankyou! Thankyou so much! we've got it Prakhar.

Comment: @BrianOwuoche You are most welcome.. please accept and vote up if the answer worked :)